# Store/retrieve users passwords on server (using password managers ?)

Tags: password-management, server

I am working on a project in wich a school's server will need to use students' passwords periodically to connect to another website for them.

I am aware that storing users' passwords in a server database is a horrible idea. Besides I can't hash them because my application needs to use the original passwords.

I wonder if I could encrypt and decrypt those passwords in the database the way password managers do. Without a chance that I (or server administrators) can read them of course.

Also, do you know of any online password manager that provides an API I could safely use on my server with PHP ? Or a password manager software that I could install on the server and use with PHP ?

Comment: Do you have any control on the remote website? The best would be to have a dedicated access to be used by this automated access. In all cases, if the server needs to be able to decipher the password in an automated way, then the server administrators (at least) will also have access to them.

Comment: Is it not possible to use OAuth or a similar system?

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf : Unfortunately I don't have any control on the remote website and the owners won't create dedicated access to my team as we are students.

Comment: @S.L.Barth : The remote website is very proprietary and doesn't provide any API. I have to use Selenium and PhantomJS to read data from it.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to recommend a solution since you're asking to break a lot of basic security principles. Why does your service need to log in as the users? Can the users not log into the 3rd party service themselves?

Comment: @schroeder : My service will periodically connect to the remote website to check for new content and, if necessary, send an e-mail.

Comment: Using someone's credentials to provide service for that person screams for trouble.

Comment: The "will need" in your first sentence isn't sufficiently justified. I won't help you because by doing so I would promote the practice of inpersonating users. Doing this with password should be prohibited to the users. Admins and most notably security admins shouldn't do it, and… **shouldn't help it**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a kind of Vault for storing secrets. There is an Open Source project named Vault at https://vaultproject.io/. It provides a lot of options and access control. Take a look.

As others already said, this is bad practice. Authentication is made to link virtual account with physical person. That's actually breaking this.